# Jquery Datepicker for month and year only

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am working on this datepicker. My code works fine separately but when I use it with the whole application it shows the empty textbox next to the Date Label. I have created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/O0WoQukQi2GDDwCrdDJu?p=preview). Need help.

As my whole code is huge please [check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/O0WoQukQi2GDDwCrdDJu?p=preview). Here is just one file from my code datepicker.js :

```
$(function () {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include this

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

script:

```
  $(function() 
  {   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       changeMonth:true,
       changeYear:true,
       yearRange:"-50:+50",
       dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd" });
   });
```

And

```
<label>Date</label><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"/>
```

This will work.